# spring file uploading in complex folrm

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, forms, file-upload

We are moving to Spring MVC and stucked with froms... Is it possible to upload file with spring if the form is complex? I mean I have a few text fields(such as name, department, position) and a file. I googled but found nothing useful.

Comment: Have you checked Spring docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart?

Comment: of course...it was the first place I checked...

Comment: It is possible. What issues, if any, are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

Damn! it's so easy! http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/975/spring-3-file-upload-example/